# Disable -enable-default-pie for gcc

Tags: gcc

I need to disable the `-enable-default-pie` option in the configuration of gcc, but I don't know how to do it. Is there a text file where I simply have to delete that option or how should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a different configuration for the GCC, you need to recompile it.

### Download GCC

[Download](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) or [clone](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror) the GCC from the official website. As alternative, you can also install it from the Ubuntu source packages.

```
# Download gcc
$ wget https://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-7.3.0/gcc-7.3.0.tar.xz
$ tar xf gcc-7.3.0.tar.xz
$ cd gcc-7.3.0

# Clone gcc
$ git clone https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git
$ cd gcc; git checkout gcc-7_3_0-release

# Use Ubuntu sources
$ apt-get source gcc-7
$ cd gcc-7-7.3.0
```

### Configure GCC

Enter the GCC source folder and run the autoconf script `configure`. Before that, all development libraries for gcc need to be installed. Most common case `configure` only requires the languages c and c++ (see also [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) page). This is also the place, where you should put the custom option `--enable-default-pie`.

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep gcc-7
$ configure --enable-languages=c,c++
```

### Build and Install

Simple start `make` and `make install`. This will build and install the custom gcc in `/usr/local/bin`. If you need a different location, you can change that with the `--prefix=...` option in the configuration step.

```
$ make -j $(grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo)
$ sudo make install

# Or better with checkinstall which, creates a deb packet
$ sudo checkinstall make install
```

Depending on the amount of CPUs you have, this can take a while. After that, just run `gcc --version` and watch the new compiler in action.

Comment: Your method is for [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) or other source-based distro. What was wrong with getting source of [GCC from repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all) with `apt-get source gcc`, `sudo apt-get build-dep gcc` and then configure it and then run `sudo checkinstall make install`?

Comment: Nothing, it is just a choice of gcc versions. If the gcc versions doesn’t fit your needs.